# C++ dealing with files

Tags: c++, file

I have a problem working in C++ with txt files.. First of all, I want to make a program which
have .cpp and .h files.. which have classes and functions.

So here is my problem:

for example, i have txt file which contains 5 lines of text (players names). So I want to make every line of that txt to be a variable of string.. But as long as I want to use that new variables they suddently disappears.

Here is program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    int i;
    string player[5];

    ifstream myfile ("1-Efes Pilsen.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                getline (myfile,line);
                player[i] = line;
            }
            // after this point I still can use new variables
        }
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    cout << player[1]; // <--- NOT WORKING. WHY?

    myfile.close();   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 3):

While it is not clear to me how it's not working, I can *guess* that there are more contents in the file than just 5 strings (perhaps another newline) which causes the `while` condition to evaluate to `true` causing the `for` loop to read 5 lines (which will fail and not actually read anything) and replace the good values in the string array with crappy ones (empty string).

Instead of having an outer `while` loop, you probably want to add the condition to the `for` loop itself; something along the lines of:

```
for (i=0;i<5 && myfile.good();i++)
{
   getline (myfile,line);
   player[i] = line;
}
```

Comment: For(int I=0;I<5 && getline(myfile,player[i]); ++I)  ;

Comment: All hail Mehrdad Afshari ! :)

Comment: @MooingDuck Indeed. I wanted to keep things clear and didn't want to diverge from the core issue, so I'll keep my answer as is.

Comment: Generally one puts getline in the condition.  At least put in a break/exception to clarify when a line is not read?

Comment: It really depends on the expected format of the text file. I think for OP's use case, you style makes more sense.